# free text search box for dojo enhancedgrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

Is it possible to have a free text search box on top of a dojo enhancedgrid, which I can type in text and it immediately filter out rows that do not contain the text?

I am aware of the filter plugin and that is not what I prefer.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If depends on how you grid view is bind. If it's bind to a ItemFileReadStore you can easily filter it:

```
  store.fetch({ query: { filterCol: filterValue }, onComplete: function completed(items,findResult) {
                    store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data: { items: items, identifier: 'YourStoreIdentifier'} });}                          
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

grid.setQuery({name: 'a%'})
will call server on a JsonRest store with query string name=...